# Workflow Email – Yes/No and Timing Notification

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, notifications, outgoing-email

I am trying to set up a workflow that will

- send out an email once a “No” in a Yes/No column is left on No for 5 weeks and
- will continue to send out an email on a weekly basis until that field is changed to yes.

Comment: Which version SharePoint? SharePoint Designer 2013 style workflows support loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try to go through this logic:**

- Create a new variable as date called `Today` then set it to Current Date. (for calculating 5 weeks)
- Create a new variable as date called `Today_weekly` then set it to Current Date. (for calculating weekly)
- Create a new variable as boolean called `5weeks` as then set it to **No** and (for tracking 5 weeks)
- Use loop to **Loop with condition** until `Status` field become **Yes**
- Use **If-Else** condition to check if the 5weeks variable becomes **Yes**

  - If yes, send an email and wait for next week to check if the `Status` value becomes **yes**
  - else, wait 1 month + 7 days that approximately equal 5 weeks then set `5weeks` to `Yes`

[image]